# Temporal table alternative for CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We're trying to implement temporal table like feature for our COSMOS Database where we need to track changes in our DB. Is there any alternative to temporal table for CosmosDB? If not what would be the best way to implement the DB-change-tracking functionality? I'm aware about the CosmosDB Trigger and was planning to use that as of now, any other ideas apart from this?

Comment: I probably fail to understand what you are actually trying to do... but have you looked at the change feed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to 'track' data changes, as a document based db is schemaless, so you won't be able to do it.

If my assumption is correct, the best you can do is use Change Feed. Then, you can use an Azure Function to subscribe for the events and log them in another collection or somewhere else.

[image]

More info:

https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/08-change_feed_with_azure_functions.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed